# Debian Remove a Line from Resolv.conf

Tags: networking, debian, nameserver, resolv.conf

I was trying to change the Google DNS servers to OpenDNS in my resolv.conf file and accidentally added them incorrectly. Now my resolv.conf file looks like this:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220
```

I was able to properly change the Google nameservers to OpenDNS by editing `/etc/networking/interfaces` but now I have those two OpenDNS IPs at the bottom that I'd like to get rid of, but I can't directly edit this resolv.conf file.

How can I remove those two lines or reset this file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you don't have any servers in */etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head* or any other file in this directory. They often contain unnecessary data added during configuration of *resolvconf* package.

The head file should only contain a commented-out header.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix it by removing them from `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`, then running `sudo resolvconf -u`